# Xdebug: connection from any host

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm using Xdebug on a virtual machine (Ubuntu guest).
I'm using [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) to manage these VM and I'm configuring a "pattern" OS to clone it for web develop.
The problem is that I want to configure this ubuntu guest to accept connection to xdebug from any host (xdebug is obviously in the guest os).

These instructions don't work:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

The only way seems to add a line with:

```
xdebug.remote_host=sdurzu
```

"sdurzu" is the hostname of the host, but I want to create an "universal" configuration for xdebug, not based on host name or IP.

Is there a way to use a wild card (*) or something like this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [Xdebug settings documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings), `remote_host` is ignored if you have `remote_connect_back` enabled.

> xdebug.remote_connect_back
>   Type: boolean, Default value: 0, Introduced in Xdebug >= 2.1
>
> If enabled, the xdebug.remote_host setting is ignored and Xdebug will try to connect to the client that made the HTTP request. It checks the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variables to find out which IP address to use.
>   [...]

Also, `remote_connect_back` *should* allow any device to connect to Xdebug that has access to your web server.

Answer (score 5):

remote_host is ignored if remote_connect_back is enabled, so setting the remote_host to a hostname makes no sense. Of course, unless you use a really old version of Xdebug. In order to find out what happens under the hood you need to turn on the xdebug.remote_log - this will write connection attempts into a log file and will let you know if it can't connect as well.